# Using Rvest on multiple urls to get Youtube Channel subscriber number

Tags: r, rvest

I have a function using rvest to scrape youtube channel subscriber numbers

```
> for (i in number){
+ ymca = url[i]
+ ymca=read_html(ymca)
+ ymca=html_nodes(ymca,"#c4-primary-header-contents .yt-uix-tooltip")
+ ymca=html_text(ymca)
+ ymca=as.numeric(ymca)
+ socialmedia$Subscribers[i]=ymca
+ }

>number = (1:nrow(socialmedia))
>url = paste(socialmedia$youtube)
```

This is the function I've tried. 
It did work on the first row of the socialmedia data I'm using.
But once it hits the second row, which does not have a url (because the particular entity didn't have a youtube channel) I get an error: '' does not exist in current working directory.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `lapply(url_list, read_html)`?

Comment: You can `lapply` the whole chain with an anonymous function: `lapply(url_list, function(url){url %>% read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("#c4-primary-header-contents .yt-uix-tooltip") %>% html_text()})`

Comment: would the url_list be youtube$url (dataframe name is youtube and the column head name is url)

Comment: We have deleted your [exact duplicate of this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009649/rvest-beginner-getting-texts-from-multiple-urls-utilizing-rvest).  In the future, if you do not get satisfactory help on a post, please revise it and make improvements.  Do not post the exact same question again.

Comment: If `youtube$url` is a column of URLs, then sure. A list or character vector of URLs would work, too.

Comment: Your code doesn't work.